# jquery validation message not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

here is my html

```
<input class="required" id="AcceptTerms" name="AcceptTerms" type="checkbox" value="true" aria-required="true">
```

here is my JavaScript

```
//make sure user accepts terms 
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        AcceptTerms: 'required'
    },
    messages: {
        AcceptTerms: 'You should accept terms in order to proceed'
    }
});
```

and the error message is 'This field is required.'

**why is it not displaying my custom message ?**

Comment: Can you make fiddle? Which jQuery plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form validation runs on submiting form:

You can see complete code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlanKis/Lxmb4pg3/)

```
<form>
<input class="required" id="AcceptTerms" name="AcceptTerms" type="checkbox" value="true" aria-required="true">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

JS code is bellow:

```
$( 'form' ).validate({
  rules: {
    AcceptTerms : 'required'

  },
  messages: {
      AcceptTerms : 'You should accept terms in order to proceed'
  }
});
```

Both examples, works, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlanKis/Lxmb4pg3/1/).

Comment: Ok it works but its not the same as your code here, overthere it shows required: true

Answer (score -1):

I have written simple clean JavaScript for you purpose.

```
<script>
function validate(){
if(!document.getElementById("AcceptTerms").checked)
    alert("You should accept terms in order to proceed!");
else
    alert("Proceed.");
}
</script>
<html>
<label for="AcceptTerms">Accept Terms</label>
<input class="required" id="AcceptTerms" name="AcceptTerms" type="checkbox" aria-required="true"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate();"/>
</html>
```

Comment: correct! but that's not my issue, i asked whey is it not displaying my custom message

Comment: Because the form is not getting submitted. I have added the code to my answer. Try it.

Comment: i'm still not getting my custom message

Comment: Did you removed the aria-required="true"?

Comment: well did you try it before you posted this? do you know what aria-required="true" does?

Comment: Yes I guess. The aria-required attribute is used to indicate that user input is required on an element before a form can be submitted. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute

Comment: the aria-required is used by java script to keep track if the item is required and even if you remove it, JavaScript will put it back before validation, and no! that does not help me display my message.

Comment: Have edited my answer. Have a look, it might help you now.